# How does a compiler store information about an array's size?

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-construction, internals

Recently I read on [IsoCpp](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#num-elems-in-new-array) about how compiler known size of array created with `new`. The FAQ describes two ways of implementation, but so basically and without any internal information. I tried to find an implementation of these mechanisms in STL sources from Microsoft and [GCC](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B), but as I see, both of them just call the `malloc` internally. I tried to go deeper and found an [implementation](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.c) of the `malloc` function in GCC, but I couldn't figure out where the magic happens.
Is it possible to find how this works, or it implemented in system runtime libraries?

Comment: Does the compiler need to store the array size?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis You don't provide any parameters in delete[] call, but your program knows how many elements need to destroy. So, this information must be stored somewhere...

Comment: *I tried to find an implementation of these mechanisms in STL sources* -- Well, you won't find it there -- STL is nothing more than complex C++ code, no different than the code you would write if you were experienced enough.  You need to look at the actual compiler's heap management system and how it is implemented.

Comment: From your link, emphasis added: "The **run-time system** stores the number of objects…" That's not the compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is where the compiler stores the size in the source code for GCC: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/gcc/cp/init.c#L3319-L3325

And the equivalent place in the source code for Clang: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/c11051a4001c7f89e8655f1776a75110a562a45e/clang/lib/CodeGen/ItaniumCXXABI.cpp#L2183-L2185

What the compilers do is store a ["cookie"](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#array-cookies) which is the number of elements allocated (the `N` in `new T[N]`) immediately before the pointer that `new T[N]` returns. This in turn means that a few extra bytes have to be allocated in the call to `operator new[]`. The compiler generates code to do this at runtime.

`operator new[](std::size_t x)` itself does no work: It simply allocates `x` bytes. The compiler makes `new T[N]` call `operator new[](sizeof(T) * N + cookie_size)`.

The compiler does not "know" the size (it's a run-time value), but it knows how to generate code to retrieve the size on a subsequent `delete[] p`.

Answer (score 2):

At least for GCC targeting x86_64, it is possible to investigate this question by looking at the assembly GCC generates for this simple program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
  int x, y;
  ~Foo() { std::cout << "Delete foo " << this << std::endl; }
};

Foo * create()
{
  return new Foo[8];
}

void destroy(Foo * p)
{
  delete[] p;
}

int main()
{
  destroy(create());
}
```

Using [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/bh5ea9631), we see this code generated for the `create` function:

```cpp
create():
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, 72
        call    operator new[](unsigned long)
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax], 8
        add     rax, 8
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

It looks to me like the compiler is calling `operator new[]` to allocate 72 bytes of memory, which is 8 bytes more than is needed for the storage of the objects (8 * 8 = 64).  Then it is storing the object count (8) at the beginning of this allocation, and adding 8 bytes to the pointer before returning it, so the pointer points to the first object.

This is one of the methods what was listed in the [document](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#num-elems-in-new-array) you linked to:

> Over-allocate the array and put n just to the left of the first Fred object.

I searched a little bit in the source code of libstdc++ to see if this was implmented by the standard library or the compiler, and I think it's actually implemented by the compiler itself, though I could be wrong.

Comment: You can see that GCC stores the count: `mov     QWORD PTR [rax], 8`. If you also looked at the code generated for `delete[]`, you'd see a loop around a call to `~Foo()`. However, that doesn't prove anything: it could be in libstdc++, and then inlined by the compiler.

Comment: The Standard is pretty loose when it comes to implementation details. This allows C++ to be implemented by a level 17 Magic User who has access to the horn of a unicorn, some pixie dust, and the shoes of a Smurf.